Unusual drawing of amine hydrochloride

why is the Cl־- H written outside without any bond here?

The form of the substance is a hydrochloride salt. $\ce{H+}$ bonds to a nitrogen and the $\ce{Cl-}$ is ionically bound to the pronated nitrogen species.

The acidic hydrogen atom from $\ce{HCl}$ is attached to one of the two nitrogen atoms. And the published formula is not interested in informing which one.

The basicity of the di-phenylated nitrogen would be significantly less than of the mono-phenlyated nitrogen, so the H+ should preferentially rest on that one - unless crystal packing reoriented the phenyls and/or favored the other nitrogen. In solution, the mono-phenylated nitrogen should always get the H+.

It is a hydrochloride salt which results from the reaction of hydrochloric acid to an organic base, in this case the amine. The chloride ion has an ionic bond to the protonated nitrogen species and $\ce{H+}$ is bonded to nitrogen (if the acidic hydrogen is not given then the species can be considered in diazonium form, although some sources indicate the diazonium bond to be between the two benzene). The $\ce{HCl}$ is written separately from the organic entity or sometimes written as a dot (see purpose of dot in formula).

Diazonium? Are you sure? I cannot see that in the given structure.

I never said the given compound is a diazonium. I said that if the hydrogen is not there, then the species can be considered in diazonium form. I have clarified in my answer @Snijderfrey

Ah well, I still think it can be misunderstood easily.

The other answers generally cover the type of notation used. However, there is still no good reason to draw the structure like it is because it is simply wrong. There is no negative charge on $\ce{HCl}$, it is a neutral molecule. Quite obviously, the net charge of the structure as drawn is negative which also makes no sense and does not conform to the compound name.

It is a salt which results from the reaction of hydrochloric acid with the amine. There are two possible ammonium salts and it is possible that the actual site of protonation is either unknown, or not relevant (the pKas will be very similar).

You should read previous answers before writing yours. This answer does not add anything substantial to the previous answer written 23 hours before.

The previous answer is wrong - there is no diazonium structure in the compound given.

I never claimed it to be a diazonium compound.

The peas of the two nitrogens will be significantly different.
